# Core Data need help(beginner)

Tags: objective-c, ipad, core-data, ios5

I trying to make a Web Service application which will run when the program is on the background too and i will fetch my data from tree different URLs from my server. I read almost all of [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001200-SW1) and also [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started) tutorials and even i watched [CS193p Core Data Lectures](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/) too but still i cant get started with coding. This is my first Iphone(ipad) application, i use `NSJSONSerialization` for parsing. Can anyone please explain a little

- How many ManagedObjectContext s i need to declare?
- How to save data which come from different classes to the same entity?
- (The mos important) From where to get started with coding..
  I think this is a kind of not wanted questioning but i really need help. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should probably start with a less ambitious project. Core data is sort of advanced stuff.

Comment: @Mundi my app needs to run on backgroun and has some complex data graph. Tere is no way to do  this expect this(as far as i know)

Comment: Understood, but if you do not understand Apple's CoreDataRecipies sample or Prof. Hegarty's lecture, you should first do another project to get more familiar with objective-C.

Comment: I think you are right bro:) +1 for comment

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest taking one of the core data sample apps from the ADC site and looking at how it's structured. You may even be able to adapt the code to your application. CoreRecipes is a great sample to learn from.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thanks for answer but i have looked it before, that is true it is a very good sample but i couldn't realize yet. I need some step-by-step code. I mean, if you please, say that: define this this and this properties and use these methods after pparsing the data.. I need some code, but in some explanation –